# Meaning of `To move through these moments`

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, american-english

`To move through these moments`  I have heard this line on CNN USA. And the person was talking about a difficult time in a family and what needs to be done to move through these moments. I couldn't find this phrase in any online dictionary

Comment: Respect to the dictionaries! Isn't it just a twee version of "to get through this time"?

Comment: Is there a correspondence between `get` and `move` ? How to understand that the phrase is similar to `to get through this time` ? What I understand is the phrasal verb here is `Get through`

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Could you please help me or slight assistance in making me notice the transformation from one sentence to other

Comment: @OldBrixtonian What exactly do you mean by twee here?

Comment: To [get through](https://www.lexico.com/definition/get_through) is to pass a difficult or testing experience or period. We say, "It's hard getting through these times". Or we might say _how_ we get through such times. We wouldn't normally describe what we need to do "to move through these moments".  "She Moved Through The Fair" is a very pretty folk song; its language a little unworldly. But saying we move through the moments - with the assonance of its repeated m's - sounds like a sentimental song or poem: a little [fey](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fey) . . .

Comment: . . . and a little [twee](https://www.lexico.com/definition/twee). But perhaps it's a matter of taste.